# align to baseline grid css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit: This question is about aligning to a baseline. Meaning the base of the characters (the bottom of character 'h'). When including 2 different font sizes of the text 'jh', being able to align them at baseline with `div`. I could not find any solution for aligning to a baseline grid on the internet. They all stink. Without a Javascript framework or css preprocessor. This makes no sense if the proportion of the font below the baseline is known.

For the code linked below: Change .text2 font-size to 22px, and observe the two text groups are no longer aligned at the baseline (the bottom of the 'h'). Change it back to 32 px and they are aligned. Given the .bottomalign class has em units, both fonts are in arial, and em refers to font size, the descenders of the 'j' would be an equal proportion in both text groups, so any ideas why it dosnt align big genius if you no the answer. will be giving bounty if no one knows this.

http://jsfiddle.net/FX5zq/

**css:**

```
.bottomalign
{
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  bottom: -.24em;
}

.container
{
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}

div
{
  font-family: arial;
}

.text1
{
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text2
{
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: green;
}
```

**html:**

```
 <div class="container">

      <div class="bottomalign text1">jh</div>
      <div class="bottomalign text2">jh</div>

 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: re-format your question that can understand what you want exactly is....

Comment: any ideas why it dosnt align

Comment: I'm not clear with your question...

Comment: when .text2 is set to 32px font size, the two fonts are aligned at a baseline. when it is set to 22px the .text2 is above the baseline. view the jsfiddle

Comment: How 16px and 32px will get aligned?

Comment: ok ill reformat it to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Can you show your requirement as a image?

Comment: view edit. taken from the jsfiddle link

Comment: How about setting  `bottom: 0` on `.bottomalign` instead of `-.24em`. See http://jsfiddle.net/FX5zq/2/

Comment: that does not align to the baseline, only bottom of the j. And it would look bad side by side because text should be aligned at baseline

Comment: Are you trying to create Text Shadow effect here?

Comment: no. just baseline alignment. it looks like text shdow because this allows the baseline nonalignment to be more visible. obviously there are frameworks available but all use javascript or other language.

Comment: Have you tried setting the line-height to the same height?

Comment: it doesnt work. Also read an article once that said line-height centers the text vertically. not to baseline. using a table is the solution with vertical-align=baseline. but no idea y it wouldnt work in a div with the css since em is relative to font size, so if it works for 32 px with bottom: -.24em, why wouldnt it for 22px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is default line-height varies among different browsers: mozilla is about 1.2, so for the code above to work, it needed a line height reset:

```
.bottomalign
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.17em; //arial descends 17% below baseline
  line-height: 1;
}
```

read http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/inline-format.html

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to set the divs to `display: inline-block; vertical-align: baseline;`. That way, they'll align as you need no matter what size. http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/ucyIt

Edit: second option, mentioned in the note:
http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/jBcxk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font-family: arial;
}

.container div {
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.text1 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.text2 {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: green;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="text1">jh</div>
    <div class="text2">jh</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. Even better would be to be able to align them to the bottom of the div container as the baseline. Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean with the descenders hanging out of the div? What is your real aim here? There might be a better way.

Comment: being able to align them at the bottom border line of a div with a specified height. In my question the container had height: 50px, and the text inside is positioned at absolute, bottom -.24 em. The point is to be able to specify exactly where the baseline is in the page without javascript or a css preprocessor

Comment: That kind of placement is probably asking for trouble. After a bit of playing around, I came up with this, but I wouldn't rely on it too greatly: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/jBcxk

Comment: nice code. Thanks. but it hard codes the pixel values. of the relative positioning. The code in the question attempts to make one css class (bottomalign) that aligns every text that is arial to the bottom of a div container that has a specified height (possibly hard coded).

Comment: Without having to recalcalate the bottom relative positioning. which is why ems would be ideal. And cross browser so no css calc function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript code which will adjust the two divs dynamically. Ignore if you are looking for an answer based on css only:

you will have to remove "bottom: -.24em;" from bottomalign class and use the following script tag

document.getElementsByClassName("bottomalign text1")[0].style.top = document.getElementsByClassName("bottomalign text2")[0].clientHeight - document.getElementsByClassName("bottomalign text1")[0].clientHeight - 1 + 'px';

Code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.bottomalign
{
  position: absolute;
  float: left;

}

.container
{
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}

div
{
  font-family: arial;
}

.text1
{
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text2
{
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

      <div class="bottomalign text1">jh</div>
      <div class="bottomalign text2">jh</div>
    <script language="javascript"> document.getElementsByClassName("bottomalign text1")[0].style.top = document.getElementsByClassName("bottomalign text2")

[0].clientHeight - document.getElementsByClassName("bottomalign text1")[0].clientHeight - 1 + 'px'; </script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out a little something and am very interested to know if this is what you are looking for.

TL:DR;
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koedood/1qe60w33/)

What I did was make use of `display: table-cell;`. Using your HTML, I used the following CSS:

```
.bottomalign {
    display: table-cell;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
    display: table;
}
div {
    font-family: arial;
}
.text1 {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.text2 {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: green;
}
```

I gave the container a `display: table;` and the bottomalign `display: table-cell;`

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks. My answer is what i was looking for: it allows the code to 1) resize the text without changing its baseline, and 2) to move the baseline around without changing anything. This is a solution but the text will move if resized.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this now, with `display: flex` and `align-self: flex-end`:

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 24em;
}

.bottom-align {
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-align-self: flex-end;
    -o-align-self: flex-end;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.text-1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

.text-2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

I have [updated your  solution](http://jsfiddle.net/FX5zq/29/).

Please note that the flexbox specification is still changing, and you will have to use prefixes for now, unless you use a tool like [autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer).

Comment: the jsfiddle is showing them aligned at the bottom of the box. But i wanted the baseline of the characters to be aligned also, hanging out of the box, to be able to precisely position the baseline of the text by pixel on the screen. This library calculates the baseline ratio of text https://github.com/nathanhammond/baseline-ratio/blob/master/baseline-ratio.js